# AssertTrue need to be used in cucumber BDD JUNIT JAVA SELENIUM INTELLIJ

Tags: requirements-validation, serenity-bdd, cucumber-java

If I need to validate video1 should have some video attached similarly video2 has one video attached and video 3 has video attached whether it is attached or not. Can anyone explain me with this. Using cucumber BDD ,junit,selenium ,

Web UI to check whether all video is upload or not

Suppose Video1. : (Colon : only comes when video is attached so like wise video2 and video3 ) all 3 has video attached . We need to validate whether all 3 : are present or not if not then should which video don’t have

Comment: Could you give us some more detail, please? Is this a web application that lists videos and should show the video files? Please edit your question to tell us more about the scenario you need to test, and the problem you are having.

Comment: To add to Kate's questions, what are you expecting? An HTML link? Checking the src value of a link? Whether a video frame is shown? Video controls work?

Comment: Suppose   Video1.  :    (Colon : only comes when video is attached so like wise video2 and video3 ) all 3 has video attached . We need to validate whether all 3 : are present or not if not then should which video don’t have :

Comment: @RituPrasad I would suggest sharing some screenshots / DOM snippets with clear references the videos you are mentioning, then show the code that you have so far, and what problem you are seeing. (Aside, some commas probably will help us to understand the situation :) )

Answer (score 0):

To validate whether all three videos have been uploaded or not, you can use the AssertTrue method in your cucumber BDD test case.

Here's an example code snippet:

```
@Then("I should see all three videos uploaded")
public void i_should_see_all_videos_uploaded() {
    boolean video1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_of_video1")).getText().contains(":");
    boolean video2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_of_video2")).getText().contains(":");
    boolean video3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_of_video3")).getText().contains(":");
    
    assertTrue("Video1 is not uploaded", video1);
    assertTrue("Video2 is not uploaded", video2);
    assertTrue("Video3 is not uploaded", video3);
}
```

In the above example, we are checking whether the text of each video element contains a colon (:) which indicates that the video has been uploaded. If any of the videos are not uploaded, the test will fail and the message passed to the assertTrue method will be displayed.

You can replace the xpath_of_video1, xpath_of_video2, and xpath_of_video3 with the actual XPath of each video element on the page.

Make sure to import the AssertTrue method from the JUnit framework as follows:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
```

I hope this helps!